# Alternative to numpy.rate() function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Hey I have been using numpy rate() function previously but recently I found out that this particular function has been deprecated. Is there any alternative for this function?

I have been searching numpy.financial() documentation but was not able to find anything.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: On the main documentation [page](https://numpy.org/numpy-financial/latest/index.html) is this [link](https://numpy.org/numpy-financial/latest/rate.html#numpy_financial.rate).

Comment: Hi thanks yes I found it I got confused sorry for posting the query.